# Angularjs nested directives scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Please refer to [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uc8SYR0hfayz4lqnyxlD).
The problem: when I use item-over directive inside main controller it triggers fine OnOver. This works OK:

```
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in main.Data" item-over="main.OnOver(item)">{{item.Name}}</a>
```

But when I put it inside list-view directive it doesn't trigger the controller's OnOver method. This doesn't work:

```
<list-view itemssource="main.Data">
  <a href="#" item-over="main.OnOver(item)">{{item.Name}}</a>
</list-view>
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: show your directive codes

Comment: It's in Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/uc8SYR0hfayz4lqnyxlD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that listView directive is creating isolated scope, so you can't access main or item inside scope of this directive. Even onOver would not be accessible because it belongs to parent scope,

If you are not in particular need to two way binding for itemSource in listview directive then make the directive inherit parent scope by setting `scope: true` in return statement.

use attr in your directive to access attr value without creating isolated scope-

```
return {
   link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.itemsSource = attrs.itemsSource
   }
}
```

you will pass the itemsSource same way -

`<list-view items-source="main.Data">`

Now you have the values in your directive scope and you can play with them.

OR since you are inherting the parent scope you can directly access the value using $parent - inside your directive:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    scope.itemsSource = scope.$parent.itemsSource
}
```

On checking plunkr there were some more problems, check this working example of your plunkr - [working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ToNK3WBWqOpgfqjnIOel?p=info)

Comment: I don't need 2way binding for itemssource...but if i set scope: true in listView directive, how then i will refer to itemssource in Link function of listView directive? And then how I should bind to itemssource in the template of listView directive?

Comment: I have updated answer showing how to use attributes without creating isolated scope